# interaction of time.sleep with threading.Lock

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am trying to understand locks in Python and wrote the following sample code.

```
import threading
import time

LOCK = threading.Lock()

class Printer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Printer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.daemon = True
        self.i = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            with LOCK:
                print(self.i)
                self.i += 1
            time.sleep(1)

raw_input('press enter to start thread\n')
Printer().start()
raw_input('press enter to pause thread\n')
LOCK.acquire()
raw_input('press enter to resume thread\n')
LOCK.release()
raw_input('press enter to exit program\n')
print('bye!')
```

This is working as expected and produces output such as this:

```
press enter to start thread

0
 press enter to pause thread
1
2
3
4

press enter to resume thread

press enter to exit program
5
6
7
8

bye!
```

**Question**

Why does indenting `time.sleep(1)` inside the `with` block break the program?

With

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        with LOCK:
            print(self.i)
            self.i += 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

the printer cannot be interrupted!

Comment: What exactly do you mean it can't be interrupted?

Comment: @martineau Pressing enter to pause the thread does nothing, it keeps printing.

Comment: @martineau actually, what I just said is wrong. Apparently it sometimes just takes very long (dozens of rounds of the printer's loop) for the main thread to acquire the lock.

Comment: Well, indenting it and putting inside the `with LOCK:` means the thread sleeps with the lock acquired — which will prevent any other thread, such as the main one, from acquiring it while its sleeping.

Comment: Sure, in principle I understood that. What I did not realize before Hameda169's answer that if the sleep is done within the locked zone, then the thread tries to acquire the lock immediately after releasing it. Thus it's likely that it will win a few (or many) rounds of acquiring the lock versus the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this and see what's happening:

```
import threading
import time

LOCK = threading.Lock()


class Printer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Printer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.daemon = True
        self.i = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            with LOCK:
                print(self.i)
                self.i += 1
                time.sleep(1)


raw_input('press enter to start thread\n')
Printer().start()
raw_input('press enter to pause thread\n')
print('acquiring...')
LOCK.acquire()
print('acquired')
raw_input('press enter to resume thread\n')
LOCK.release()
raw_input('press enter to exit program\n')
print('bye!')
```

when your code tries to run `LOCK.acquire()` I think a race begins between `with LOCK` and `LOCK.acquire()` and the thread wins the game most of time and acquires LOCK for 1 second. But in the first method, when Printer() is waiting for 1 second, the Main thread acquires LOCK without any problem because it's free. I hope you get it. sorry for my language :))

Comment: I included print statements before and after `acquire` and I get something like [this](https://pastebin.com/NzZZEJGR). So what happened here is that the main thread lost five "rounds" to the printer thread when trying to acquire the lock? And furthermore, I don't see this behavior when `time.sleep` is outside of the `with` block because in that scenario the printer does not immediately try to acquire the lock again after releasing it?

Comment: I'm not sure about what I want to say, but I think it makes sense.
I think `acquire` function of `Lock` is working like this: It tries to acquire the lock. if it was successful, then returns, else it waits and tries again. and the waiting time should be increased after any fail to acquire

Answer (score 1):

[Hameda169](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58495127/10909217) figured it out!

I wrote a small demonstration GUI with an "on" and an "off" button in order to explain/remember the concept in the future.

If you comment out the `time.sleep(0.01)` after `LOCK.release()` the GUI buttons can freeze for a long time while they try to acquire the lock.

It also showcases why locks are necessary at all. If you comment out `with LOCK` in the `on` and `off` callbacks, you will very soon get an `AttributeError` when pressing the buttons.

```
# see what happens when there's no sleep AFTER release
# see what happens if on and off functions do not acquire the lock

import Tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
import ttk

class ON(object):
    pass

class Printer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Printer, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.on = None
        self.i = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            LOCK.acquire()
            if self.on is not None: 
                time.sleep(0.1) # make it very likely that self.on can be set to
                                # None from outside before trying to access
                                # dummy_attribute -> AttributeError w/o lock!
                self.on.dummy_attribute # can error without lock
                print(self.i)
                self.i += 1
            LOCK.release()

            time.sleep(0.01) # must sleep after release, else lock can be
                             # acquired immediately again!

ROOT = tk.Tk()
PRINTER = Printer()
LOCK = threading.Lock()

def on():
    with LOCK:
        PRINTER.on = ON()
        PRINTER.on.dummy_attribute = 'foo'

def off():
    with LOCK:
        PRINTER.on = None

ttk.Button(ROOT, text='on', command=on).grid()
ttk.Button(ROOT, text='off', command=off).grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PRINTER.start()
    ROOT.mainloop()
```